# Magento Customer Login is not working properly in chrome, but working fine in firefox

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento Customer Login  is not working properly in chrome browser. But working fine in firefox.

While trying to login using chrome browser, it redirects to same page. After pressing F5 only it shows the dashboard.  But in firefox it is working fine without F5.

How to resolve this problem. Any idea?

Comment: it is cookie domain ,path issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento admin panel not working in chrome](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70343/magento-admin-panel-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is the problem with session cookie with the chrome browser. So just go through this directory **/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php** in find following code and just comment its.

```
 // session cookie params
   /* $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
  */
```

after clear **var/cache/** and browser cache.

its working for me. i will hope working for you. :)

Comment: You can not edit core files directly.

Comment: yes. you need to override this file.

Comment: But you can not change magento core files. you can copy this file in local codePool . then you can change it in local codePool

Comment: i am also says that. you can override this file in local codePool.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the base url from http://localhost/ to http://127.0.0.1/

it will work

Comment: I have working in live site. So cannot put the base url like http://localhost/ to http://127.0.0.1/                        Any Other solution??

Comment: did you tried login from other computer?

Comment: Yes. I tried in other computers also. But same result..............

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution would be to setup a local domain like below:

**#1 Modify hosts file**
Lookup location: {drive}:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Add an entry like below:

> 127.0.0.1 www.mylocal.com

**#2 If you are using APACHE and WAMP/XAMPP/LAMP, navigate to httpd-vhosts.conf file**
Lookup location: (might change from OS to OS, I am on Windows) {drive}:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

Add an entry like below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin youremail@gmail.com
  DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/projects/magento"
  ServerName www.mylocal.com
  ErrorLog "logs/www.mylocal.com-error.log"
  CustomLog "logs/www.mylocal.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache Server

Type "www.local.com" in the address bar and see if it works.

> Additionally to make it work always without any issues, try setting the below under System > Configuration > General > Web > Session Cookie Management

**Cookie Domain to mylocal.com**

**Cookie Path to /**

This way you will be able to login using Chrome, Firefox and any browser. This way you will solve all cookie, session issues like Add to Cart etc.

Happy Coding...

Answer (score -1):

Comment cookies in `Varien.php` file.
File location `app/code/code/Mage/core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php`
and comment lines from `96-122`.