# Magento admin panel not working in chrome

Tags: magento-1.9

I installed latest version of magento in my Localhost but when i opened this on my server, the admin panel not redirect in chrome but on Firefox it works very well.. What the reason of this situation [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7T4N.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEZnp.png]

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `localhost` as host name.
You need to have a dot in the host name.
If you don't want to create virtual hosts use `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Create a test or development host domain name in your 'hosts' file on your local computer mapped to 127.0.0.1, chrome seems to prefer true TLDs (.com etc) so I recommend using something like dev.yourdomain.com

Answer (score -1):

No this not the right answer real answer is to comment 85 to 102 line in varien.php file of magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php

Comment: This is not an answer rather supposed to be a comment

Comment: thanks @Rajeev i have not knot how to judge and answer the question in block ...

Comment: @User3515241. Editing the core files is never a solution. The cookie settings are there for a reason. You should never remove those lines.

Comment: in chrome this lines are creating error ....

Comment: they don't for me.